# GWT: Loading a view into main app from another app

Tags: gwt, include

Let's say you have two `GWT` applications: the first (which is **on another server** as the second) has implemented some `views` that can be used to change the configuration separately.

The other one can manage (and access) some of the first ones and should configure them without forcing the user to login on every site.

It would be bad to just copy the code of the configuration, because this would duplicate code and we have to maintain it for every version, because the configuration-dialogues can change between versions.

Is it possible to include / load that view into your main GWT app, so that the users can use it the same way as your main application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can - Display the second app in an iframe. But if you use cookies beware of same origin policy if the domains are different for the two sites.

The other solution is import the code into the new one and let it perform independently here.

(A lot depends on underlying architecture of the two apps of course)

Comment: The second solution would be bad, because this means have to duplicate code and also maintain it for every version, because the configuration-dialogues can change between versions.

Comment: You can create a separate package and reference it...you anyways always do duplicate code...your gwt modules... they are reused, so are any java jar right?